# How to recursively parse xml data into List of Map of Strings using xpath?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

Is it possible to convert XML data of any depth, to a list of Map of Strings, recursively in java.

This is my XML data:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <p:PersonalDetails>
      <Node_1>
        <Node_1_1>
          <name>name 1</name>
          <address>
            <street>17</street>
            <town>1507487</town>
          </address>
          <details>
            <detail_1>detaile item 1</detail_1>
            <detail_2>
                <detail_2_1>detail item 2_1</detail_2_1>
                <detail_2_2>detail item 2_1</detail_2_2>
            </detail_2>
           </details>
         </Node_1_1>
         <Node_1_2>
           <name>name 1</name>
           <address>
              <street>17</street>
              <town>1507487</town>
            </address>
           <details>
             <detail_1>
                <detail_1_1>
                    <detail_1_1_1>detail item 2_1_1</detail_1_1_1>
                </detail_1_1>
                <detail_1_2>detail item 2_1</detail_1_2>
              </detail_1>
              <detail_2>
                <detail_2_1>
                    <detail_2_1_1>
                        <detail_2_1_1_1>detail item 2_1_1_1</detail_2_1_1_1>
                    </detail_2_1_1>
                </detail_2_1>
              </detail_2>
            </details>
       </Node_1_2>
    </Node_1>
</p:PersonalDetails>
```

I am able to convert to a list of Map of Strings with this code:

```
    public static void testXpath(String filePath, String expr,String childSubNodeName) throws 
    ParserConfigurationException, XPathExpressionException, IOException, SAXException {
    DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(filePath);
    xmlDocument.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile("//"+expr).evaluate(xmlDocument, 
    XPathConstants.NODESET);

    List<Map<String,String>> listMap = new LinkedList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<nodeList.getLength();i++){
        NodeList childNode = (NodeList) nodeList.item(i);
        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();

        for(int j=0;j<childNode.getLength();j++){
            if(!childNode.item(j).getTextContent().equals("\n")){
                if(childNode.item(j).getNodeName().contains(childSubNode)) { //childSubnodeName
                        extractSubNode(childNode.item(j), map);
                    } else
                        map.put(childNode.item(j).getNodeName(), childNode.item(j).getTextContent());

            }
        }
        listMap.add(map);
    }
    System.out.println(listMap);
    System.out.println("-------------------------");
}

private static void extractSubNode(Node item, Map<String, String> map) {
    NodeList subNode = item.getChildNodes();
    for(int j=0;j<subNode.getLength();j++){
        if(!subNode.item(j).getTextContent().equals("\n")){
            map.put(item.getNodeName()+"."+subNode.item(j).getNodeName(),subNode.item(j).getTextContent());
        }
    }
}
```

But I can only extract 2 level deep. Is there a way I can extract XML data to any depth?

I am expecting a List of Map of Strings:

```
  [{name=name 1, address.street=17,address.town=1507487,...}]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does it have to be XPath 1.0? In Java you have access to XPath 3.1 and/or XQuery 3.1 and/or XSLT 3.0 using e.g. Saxon 10 or 11 or 12 or to XQuery 3.1 using BaseX. It is not clear, however, which mapping exactly you want, but I would figure that a perhaps recursive solution in any of the mentioned languages could construct whatever result you are looking for.

Comment: I know its possible to do with the Saxon, but i dont know how to do it, if you have any example , please link so i can refer that. please help thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your desired mapping is not clear, your input sample is not complete nor well-formed but XPath 3.1 as supported by e.g. Saxon 9.8 or later can use a single XPath 3.1 expression to return a sequence of maps e.g.

```
for $node in outermost(//Node_1/Node_1_1)
return 
  let $leaves := $node//*[not(*)]
return
  $node!map:merge(
    $leaves!map:entry(string-join((ancestor-or-self::* except $node/ancestor-or-self::*)/local-name(), '.'), string())
  )
```

at [the XPath 3.1 fiddle](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xpath31fiddle/?xpath=for%20%24node%20in%20outermost%28%2F%2FNode_1%2FNode_1_1%29%0Areturn%20%0A%20%20let%20%24leaves%20%3A%3D%20%24node%2F%2F*%5Bnot%28*%29%5D%0Areturn%0A%20%20%24node%21map%3Amerge%28%0A%20%20%20%20%24leaves%21map%3Aentry%28string-join%28%28ancestor-or-self%3A%3A*%20except%20%24node%2Fancestor-or-self%3A%3A*%29%2Flocal-name%28%29%2C%20%27.%27%29%2C%20string%28%29%29%0A%20%20%29&input=%3CNode_1%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CNode_1_1%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cname%3Ename%201%3C%2Fname%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Caddress%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cstreet%3E17%3C%2Fstreet%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctown%3E1507487%3C%2Ftown%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Faddress%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdetails%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdetail_1%3Edetaile%20item%201%3C%2Fdetail_1%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdetail_2%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdetail_2_1%3Edetail%20item%202_1%3C%2Fdetail_2_1%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdetail_2_2%3Edetail%20item%202_1%3C%2Fdetail_2_2%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdetail_2%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdetails%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FNode_1_1%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3CNode_1_2%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cname%3Ename%201%3C%2Fname%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Caddress%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cstreet%3E17%3C%2Fstreet%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctown%3E1507487%3C%2Ftown%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Faddress%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdetails%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdetail_1%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdetail_1_1%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdetail_1_1_1%3Edetail%20item%202_1_1%3C%2Fdetail_1_1_1%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdetail_1_1%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdetail_1_2%3Edetail%20item%202_1%3C%2Fdetail_1_2%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdetail_1%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdetail_2%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdetail_2_1%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdetail_2_1_1%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdetail_2_1_1_1%3Edetail%20item%202_1_1_1%3C%2Fdetail_2_1_1_1%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdetail_2_1_1%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdetail_2_1%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdetail_2%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdetails%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%3C%2FNode_1_2%3E%0D%0A%3C%2FNode_1%3E&input-type=XML) gives e.g.

```
{"address.town":"1507487","details.detail_2.detail_2_1":"detail item 2_1","details.detail_2.detail_2_2":"detail item 2_1","address.street":"17","details.detail_1":"detaile item 1","name":"name 1"}
```

Example Java code using s9api:

```
    Processor processor = new Processor(false);

    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = processor.newDocumentBuilder();

    XdmNode inputDoc = docBuilder.build(new File("sample1.xml"));

    String xpathExpresssion = "array {\n" +
            "    for $node in outermost(//Node_1/Node_1_1)\n" +
            "    return \n" +
            "      let $leaves := $node//*[not(*)]\n" +
            "    return\n" +
            "      $node!map:merge(\n" +
            "        $leaves!map:entry(string-join((ancestor-or-self::* except $node/ancestor-or-self::*)/local-name(), '.'), string())\n" +
            "      )\n" +
            "}";

    XPathCompiler xpathCompiler = processor.newXPathCompiler();
    xpathCompiler.declareNamespace("map", "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map");

    XdmItem result = xpathCompiler.evaluateSingle(xpathExpresssion, inputDoc);

    System.out.println(result);
```

That `XdmItem` is an `XdmArray` (of a `XdmMap`s), so to convert that into a Java `List<Map<String,String>>` we can use the stream API:

```
    List<Map<String,String>> javaMapList =
            ((XdmArray)result).asList().stream()
                    .map(
                         m -> m.itemAt(0).asMap().entrySet()
                         .stream()
                         .map(es -> new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>( es.getKey().getStringValue(), es.getValue().itemAt(0).getStringValue()))
                         .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue()))
                    ).collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(javaMapList);
```

or a bit more compact:

```
    List<Map<String,String>> javaMapList =
            ((XdmArray)result).asList().stream()
                    .map(
                         m -> m.itemAt(0).asMap().entrySet()
                         .stream()
                         .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey().getStringValue(), e -> e.getValue().itemAt(0).getStringValue()))
                    ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

To serialize as JSON from Java, add

```
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    Serializer serializer = processor.newSerializer(sw);
    serializer.setOutputProperty(Serializer.Property.METHOD, "json");

    processor.writeXdmValue(result, serializer);

    String resultString = sw.toString();

    System.out.println(resultString);
```

It might even be possible to get a single string result using the JAXP API and XPath 3.1 (or of course using s9api) by calling the `serialize` XPath function evaluating e.g.

```
serialize(array {
    for $node in outermost(//Node_1/Node_1_1)
    return 
      let $leaves := $node//*[not(*)]
    return
      $node!map:merge(
        $leaves!map:entry(string-join((ancestor-or-self::* except $node/ancestor-or-self::*)/local-name(), '.'), string())
      )
}, map { 'method':'json'})
```

Java code:

```
    XPathFactory saxonXPathFactory = new net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathFactoryImpl();

    String xpath31Expresssion = "serialize(array {\n" +
            "    for $node in outermost(//Node_1/Node_1_1)\n" +
            "    return \n" +
            "      let $leaves := $node//*[not(*)]\n" +
            "    return\n" +
            "      $node!map:merge(\n" +
            "        $leaves!map:entry(string-join((ancestor-or-self::* except $node/ancestor-or-self::*)/local-name(), '.'), string())\n" +
            "      )\n" +
            "}, map { 'method':'json'})";

    XPath xpath = saxonXPathFactory.newXPath();

    xpath.setNamespaceContext(new NamespaceContext() {
        @Override
        public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
            if (prefix.equals("map"))
                return "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map";
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public String getPrefix(String namespaceURI) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Iterator<String> getPrefixes(String namespaceURI) {
            return null;
        }
    });

    String result = xpath.evaluate(xpath31Expresssion, new InputSource("sample1.xml"));

    System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: yes this is the format i need. But how to link to java code?

Comment: Well, to evaluate XPath 3.1 in Saxon via its Java API see https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation11/xpath-api/s9api-xpath.html

Comment: Processor proc = new Processor(false);
XQueryCompiler comp = proc.newXQueryCompiler();
XQueryExecutable exp = ?, what should i equate to the  XQueryExecutable exp?. Thank you

Comment: Thank you very much . which dependency should i use?

Comment: The currently supported Saxon releases are 10.8, 11.4 and 12.0, 11.4 is considered the most stable so e.g. `<dependency><groupId>net.sf.saxon</groupId><artifactId>Saxon-HE</artifactId><version>11.4</version></dependency>`.

Comment: Thank you very much , Its working, I am getting the result like this [map{"name":"name 1","address.town":"1507487","details.detail_1":"detaile item 1","details.detail_2.detail_2_1":"detail item 2_1","details.detail_2.detail_2_2":"detail item 2_1","address.street":"17"}]. By anychance is there a way to avoid the namespace "map" at the beginning of the list of maps ,

Comment: So you are using the first example and print out the returned XdmItem to the console? In that case you see to `toString()` representation of the XdmItem (which is an XdmArray of XdmMaps) with adaptive serialization. If you just want a plain string then wrap the result directly in XPath into the `serialize` call e.g. `serialize(array{..}, map{'method':'json'})`.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please able to tell me how to convert xdmvalue to list of Map of strings. Sorry to bother you, There are not many resources available.

Comment: @Piya, see the edit, you can use the Java 8 and later stream API to convert such values.